# How to match the observable to an array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code:

```
//this is the code that I tried it return undefined
this.server$.subscribe(param => {
      console.log(param);
      const sample = param.find(x => x === data.server);
      console.log(sample);
    });

return this.fb.group({
  server: [data && data['server'] || '', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
});
```

The data of `this.server$` observable:

```
[{
code: "S1"
createdBy: "admin"
id: "1cUMlNRSamZHD"
name: "Server1"
status: "ACTIVE"
timeCreated: "2019-09-13 17:02:33"
timeUpdated: "2019-09-19 14:38:41"
},{
code: "S2"
createdBy: "admin"
id: "w1lPuzJ8iJQp"
name: "Server2"
status: "ACTIVE"
timeCreated: "2019-08-30 15:24:44"
timeUpdated: "2019-12-10 16:54:17"
},{
code: "S3"
createdBy: "admin"
id: "HIEkQKjpM54V"
name: "Server3"
status: "ACTIVE"
timeCreated: "2019-08-05 11:00:59"
timeUpdated: "2019-08-05 11:00:59"
},{
code: "S4"
createdBy: "admin"
id: "1foD7MVZRwYzr"
name: "Server4"
status: "ACTIVE"
timeCreated: "2019-08-30 21:06:23"
timeUpdated: "2019-12-10 16:54:22"
}]
```

For example It click the data to update.
Then the value of `data.server`

```
    server :[{
    id: 1foD7MVZRwYzr,
    code: S4,
    name: Server4
    },{
    id: HIEkQKjpM54V,
    code: S3,
    name: Server3
    }]
```

What I want here is.

When it click the item where it has two server or 1.

It should find it in the observable.

And it will display in the `nz-select multiple`

```
<nz-select formControlName="server" name="server" nzPlaceHolder="Select server(s)" [nzMode]="'multiple'" nzAllowClear>
              <nz-option *ngFor="let server of (server$ | async)" [nzLabel]="server.name" [nzValue]="server"></nz-option>
            </nz-select>
```

It should display on the `nz-select` Server4 and Server3

```
const server = this.server$.value.filter(param => data.server.find(x => x.id === param.id));
```

I tried this it work, but it doesn't display on the `nz-select`

Comment: you should read the documentation for subscribe

Comment: i tried this ```const server = this.server$.value.filter(param => data.server.find(x => x.id === param.id));``` but it doesn't display on the ```nz-select```

Comment: What do you think the scope of the const is? Such a declaration is never going to be in-scope in the template for binding

Comment: @Panda What is `data['server']` meant to be? I don't see a `data` variable?

Comment: @KurtHamilton the data['server'].... ```server =[{
id: 1foD7MVZRwYzr,
code: S4,
name: Server4
},{
id: HIEkQKjpM54V,
code: S3,
name: Server3
}]```

Comment: @Panda That's not my question. **where** is the `data` variable. It's not in your question

Comment: @Panda For example: `const server = this.server$.value.filter(param => data.server.find(x => x.id === param.id));` Is data some kind of external property?

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable which stores a response:

TypeScript:

```
fooData;

this.server$.subscribe(param => {
  console.log(param);
  this.fooData = param.find(x => x === data.server);
  console.log(this.fooData);
});
```

HTML:

```
<nz-select 
    formControlName="server" name="server" 
    nzPlaceHolder="Select server(s)" [nzMode]="'multiple'" nzAllowClear>
    <nz-option 
        *ngFor="let server of fooData" 
        [nzLabel]="server.name" [nzValue]="server">
    </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

Or if you want to use `async` pipe, then you do need to call `subscribe` method as `async` pipe does it:

```
server$

ngOnInit() {
    this.server$ = this.someApMethod.getAll();
}
```

HTML:

```
<nz-select formControlName="server" name="server" 
    nzPlaceHolder="Select server(s)" [nzMode]="'multiple'" nzAllowClear>
    <nz-option *ngFor="let server of (server$ | async)" [nzLabel]="server.name" 
        [nzValue]="server">
    </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```